# Python: string.rfind() not working with backslash ('\')

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code gives me -1 when it should give a positive number? Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks

```
print("can python find this backslash \n? let's see!".rfind('\\'))
```

Comment: escape it or use raw string

Comment: The source code you wrote may have a backslash, but the string produced by that source code contains no backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that `\n` is interpreted as a new line. You need to either escape it or make it a raw string (note the `r` before the string in the 2nd example. It makes python treat every character literally). Take a look at this example:

```
>>> print("can python find this backslash \n? let's see!".rfind('\\'))
-1
>>> print(r"can python find this backslash \n? let's see!".rfind('\\'))
31
>>> print("can python find this backslash \\n? let's see!".rfind('\\'))
31
```

Comment: Excellent that works, thanks...however I think your 1st solution is better because it can deal with ANY special character. 2nd solution requires manipulation of the original string which is not a good thing especially if you don't know that there's \n in the first place. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: let's say the path = 'C:\Whatever'....how can I use r with path? I tried path = r path but it gives an error?

Comment: No problem :) Just notice that these are not the same strings. The first one includes a new line character while the second one includes a \ and n as literal characters that will not be translated to a new line. To make them the same the first example would need to have two backspaces (this will make `\n` again two characters rather than new line).

Comment: For paths it's common to use r strings. When declaring just do it like this: `path = r'C:\Whatever'`.

Comment: The problem is I'm not using it for a windows path. I'm using it for organization chart path so I need to do this across the entire df column

Comment: @ShadyMBA: Where did the data in the dataframe come from? You need to make sure backslash processing doesn't happen in the first place, because it's not reversible once it happens.

Comment: @Artur: `r'\'` doesn't work. The backslash prevents the second `'` from closing the string. (If it didn't work like that, you wouldn't be able to escape quotes in regexes.)

Comment: Thanks..I'll use an easy fix..replace ('\') with another character...find what I need, then return the string back as it was.

Comment: @ShadyMBA you're right, my bad. Backslash before `'` or `"` always results in escaping just as you said - this would make it hard for some use cases.

Comment: Thanks your help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Sure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is interpreted as a special character; a newline. If you `print` this string, you will see that it makes a new line, and doesn't show `\n`. You need to escape the backslash: `"\\n"`.